# How to center list of links in css/html

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to learn css/html by editing a template of website I got from the internet (it uses bootstrap), but I've hit a roadblock. 
I have a list of horizontal elements. I want these elements to be centered, but I have no idea how.
This is the code:

```
<div class="row">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#about">Over ons</a></li>
            <li><a href="#services">Diensten</a></li>
            <li><a href="#work">Projecten</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

This results in the 4 elements to be horizontal, but they aren't centered and I have no idea how to center them.

I'm new to css/html, so if you need more information, please ask.

**EDIT:** I've looked a bit more in the css, and found this:

```
header ul { padding-top: 0px; text-align:center}
header ul li { list-style: none; float: left; text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 2px; text-align: center;}
header ul li a { display: block; margin: 0 30px; color: #4d4959; text-align: center;}
```

I've added text-align:center; but this doesn't seem to work

Comment: What have you tried so far? There is no CSS in that code so obviously the won't be centered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this CSS and the text will be centered:

```css
li {
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#about">Over ons</a></li>
            <li><a href="#services">Diensten</a></li>
            <li><a href="#work">Projecten</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work (see edit in original post)

Answer (score 0):

use :  `text-align:center` like so :
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/toeku5tb/)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work (see edit in original post)

Answer (score 0):

If the width is set on .row you can use

`.row{ margin: auto;}`

on your div will be centered. I asume that the li-elements are next to each other (horizontal & ".row") so that might work.